# Utility for copying ID3v2 tags to ID3v1?

Tags: mp3, id3

I'm looking for a utility which will copy existing ID3v2 tags to ID3v1 counterparts alongside the original metadata in MP3 files.

I have some legacy hardware that I'm not giving up any time soon and it is incompatible with ID3v2, so I need both kinds of tags present in my files to keep everyone happy. I've been using EasyTAG which can create both tags in its files, but I'm looking for a way to run files through a script to automate the process.

I've been using Python's Mutagen library, but it only supports ID3v2.

Answer (score 5):

eyeD3 seems to do the trick:

```
sudo apt install eyed3
eyeD3 --to-v1.1 /path/to/file.mp3
```

You can also use wildcards:

```
eyeD3 --to-v1.1 *.mp3
```